# Unable to stop tracking JetBrains .idea files

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, git-rm, ngit

I have added the *.idea* files to my *.gitignore* file and that seems to work fine.  Since my *.idea* files were tracked already, though, earlier posts have suggested the following code, to get them out from under version control.

```
git rm -rf .idea
```

or

```
git rm -r --cached .idea
```

In either case, though, I get the message:

> fatal: pathspec '.idea' did not match any files.

When I list my files in this folder, though, *.idea* is right up top.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The second example looks like what you want to do. Perhaps you could try `git rm -r --cached .idea/` to indicate that you're removing a directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> fatal: pathspec '.idea' did not match any files.

assuming there would be no file with the name `.idea` on the path

Since you are trying to remove the entire folder change your command

```
git rm -r --cached .idea
```

to

```
git rm -r --cached .idea/
```

Comment: The the folder probably is not in the directory you are running the command from or is already not being tracked. you can go ahead and push you changes to remote and verify if that reflects.(removes the .idea folder)